# Default version of boot strap not recognized

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

So I created a web app using visual studio .net core 3.1. I see that boostrap came with it by default. So what I did was copy and paste the accordion example from bootstrap and was expecting it to work by default but it is not rendering. I double checked and see that jquery is referenced before boost strap. I checked the css and JS file and it is loaded, and there is no error in the console. Is there something else I need to do?

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Update:**
This is where I got the sample code, it is the very first example: [Bootsrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open bootstrap.js in your project,you will find the version of bootstrap is `v4.3.1`,and you are referencing the official document of `bootstrap v5.0`,so you need to add the css and js of `v5.0`.
[image]

You can try to add the css and js of `v5.0` to your _layout.cshtml.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```